# CSS only input range to change background color

Tags: css, input, range

Because we can style elements depending on their attribute I thought we could style a div depending on that value. For some reason it's not possible. Why not?

When dragging the slider to the right, I was expecting the div to turn red. It does not.

*I don't want js solutions*

```css
input[value="3"] ~ div:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="3">

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: I think it would be possible with sass.

Comment: @FabriceFabiyi Sass is generated to CSS so I don't think it would make any difference in this case.

Comment: you cannot, value is an attribute and is not updated when you change the range. Basically there is the *real* value and the attribute value that set the *real* value to the initial value

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not what I was hoping for, but it makes sense. It does not solve it, but it explains why. Thanks!